# tsconfig paths in external json

Tags: typescript, config

I was search for an option to store all paths in an external file (something like `tsconfig.paths`) and reference them from the main `tsconfig.json` file.

I remember did it in the past but now I can't find results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
  },
  ...
}
```

`tsconfig.paths.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@root/*": ["./*"],
      ...
    }
  }
}
```